# Infura Request Limitations

Tags: json-rpc, infura, balances

Are there any official information about request limitations? I know for example that there is a limit for the amount of results in `getLogs`: https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_getLogs

> requests are currently limited to 1000 results

But are there also limits in terms of `json-rpc` requests in general? E.g. how many getBalance requestst can I do per day / per hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion attached to Infura issue [#58](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/58) states that there are no rate limits on RPC requests.

> We do not currently have any rate limits, and will clearly publish
>   them if we implement them. However the production infrastructure is a
>   shared resource, so you may be seeing contention w/ other requests.
>   For us to diagnose your issue, we need exactly copies of the JSONRPC
>   requests made.

Answer (score 4):

in 2019 they introduced paid plan and limits for free plan. For RPC request 10 req/sec, 100000 req/day.

https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/ratelimits